# геокодирование адреса

Tags: координаты, геокодирование

Сотрудники компании со смартфонами обходят дома. Задача определить посетил ли сотрудник дом по конкретному адресу. Для этих целей делаем следующее. Получаем "координату адреса", сравниваем с координатой с мобильного устройства. Если "координата с мобильного устройства" попала в определенный радиус от "координаты адреса" то считаем что сотрудник посетил нужный адрес. Из за размеров и формы дома такой метод не позволяет решить поставленной задачи.

При просмотре Яндекс карты, в какое бы место на доме не поставить метку, Яндекс указывает одинаковый адрес дома. Я предполагаю, что Яндекс может привязывать координаты к конкретному адресу.
Идеи как решать задачу две

1. Получить из геокодеру по адресу все координаты которые могут быть привязаны к адресу и сравнивать координату со смартфона с ними, но вопрос как получить по адресу все возможные координаты
2. Геокодировать все координаты, снятые смартфоном и сравнивать адреса

Можно ли реализовать п.1 и как?

[image: пример]

Comment: Во всяких ГИС адрес описывается не точкой, а замкнутым многоугольником, от которого хранятся только координаты вершин.